# UIStackView spacing not working for zero valued size classes

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios-autolayout, size-classes, stackview

I have two labels inside a UIStackView with a 10 pixels spacing as a default value and a 0pixel spacing for my compact layout.

[image: stackview interface builder]

This works fine on Ipad, the spacing is of 10pixels between the two UILabels. The issue is on iPhone (compact width). The spacing is not actually 0 pixels but still 10 pixels. When debugging the view hierarchy, we can clearly see the constraint added by autolayout with a spacing of 10 pixels when the value is supposed to be zero.

[image: iPhone 8 compact layout - zero spacing]

If I update the compact value from 0 to 0.1, the spacing is properly set to zero.

[image: iPhone 8 compact layout - non-zero spacing]

The issue is presents in xcode 10.0 beta, ios 12.0 but also xcode 9.4 ios 11.4. Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: It doesn't *seem* like it should matter, but... If you set `Spacing: 0` and add a variation of `wR Spacing: 10` you will get Zero spacing on `wC` and 10 spacing on `wR`.